# Get Selection of TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My goal is to get the selected text of the TextFormField, but each time the button is pressed, the TextFormField loses its focus, and the print in the console shows only a selection between -1 and -1.

It did work a few weeks ago, did the behavior change in the latest release? I am on the stable Flutter channel. (`Flutter Channel stable, 2.5.0`)

This is my test example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Play extends StatefulWidget {
  const Play({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayState createState() => _PlayState();
}

class _PlayState extends State<Play> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _node = FocusNode();

  void _onPressed() {
    TextSelection selection = _controller.selection;

    print("selection.start: ${selection.start}");
    print("selection.end: ${selection.end}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            focusNode: _node,
            controller: _controller,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _onPressed,
            child: Text("do something"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works in my machine flutter `Channel stable, 2.0.5`

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. Can you show the rest of your Widget code?

Comment: I added the rest of the code - did you mean version 2.5.0? as that's the latest one

Comment: Check aswell in last version and its works perfectly.
Flutter --version:
Flutter 2.5.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4cc385b4b8 (7 days ago) • 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
Engine • revision f0826da7ef
Tools • Dart 2.14.0

Comment: It works perfectly fine in the latest version of flutter. Please try `flutter clean` before running the application. Most of the times that solves the problem when upgrading flutter.

Comment: I tried it with `flutter clean`, but still got the same result. Anything else I could try? Ill try maybe reinstalling flutter in general

Comment: I just corrected the example above - what hat before was one attempt to work around that issue

Comment: It's probably something else in your project that case the problem. I tried it too with Flutter 2.5.0 on iOS/Android and everything is working fine. Did you try the example code in a freshly created project?

Comment: I pasted the widget on DartPad and had the same problem. I use Flutter Web btw

Comment: Try to Use ```SelectableText```

Answer (score 1):

Since it works fine on mobile, I'd say it's a bug in Flutter, but fear not! Welcome to the world of workarounds and *temporary solutions<sup>TM</sup>*; replace your entire `_onPressed` method by this:

```
  int start = -1;
  int end = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() async {
      TextSelection selection = _controller.selection;
      if (selection.start > -1) start = selection.start;
      if (selection.end > -1) end = selection.end;
    });
  }

  void _onPressed() {
    print(start);
    print(end);
  }
```

Let me know if something is not very clear and I'll be happy to edit the answer with further explanations.

[DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1b3bc9b9d78b6133d2617d68b69b31e9&null_safety=true)

The Flutter community would love you to [file a bug report](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/bug-reports) (if it doesn't exist already)! :D

Comment: I thought about that as well but the problem with that solution is, that it doesn't recognize when the focus actually is not on the field ... but ill just wait for Flutter to fix it I guess - I wanted to make sure I didn't make a mistake by asking on SO :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "recognize when the focus is not on the field" but you can check that anywhere you want with `_node.hasFocus`. If you are talking about detecting the event you can do so with `
    _node.addListener(() {
      print('hasFocus in listener: ${_node.hasFocus}');
    });`

Comment: The progress of the bug can be followed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/90805.